# AngularJS unit testing controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm running into a problem while trying to test my controller.

I'll just throw the code out here and after that explain what the problem is.

**Controller**

```
// Controller name is handy for logging
var controllerId = 'splash';

// Define the controller on the module.
// Inject the dependencies. 
// Point to the controller definition function.
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', 'datacontext', splash]);

function splash($scope, datacontext) {
    // Using 'Controller As' syntax, so we assign this to the vm variable (for viewmodel).
    var vm = this;

    // Bindable properties and functions are placed on vm.
    vm.activate = activate;
    vm.title = 'Splash';
    vm.getRooms = function () {
        return vm.rooms;
    }
    activate();
    return vm;
    function activate() {
        datacontext.getRooms().then(function (data) {
            vm.rooms = data;
        });

    }
}
```

**Datacontext method**

```
function getRooms() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        deferred.resolve([{ id: 1, Name: "A02" }, { id: 2, Name: "A03" }]);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

**Test**

```
it('should have a splash title', inject(function($q, datacontextMock) {
    var vm = testContext.$controller('splash', { $scope: scope, datacontext: datacontextMock });

    expect(vm.title).toEqual('Splash');
    expect(vm.rooms).not.toBeNull();

    console.log(vm);
    expect(vm.rooms).toEqual(testContext.rooms);
}));
```

The problem is, the test fails.
It will tell me that vm.rooms is undefined...but it isn't.
When logging the vm with console.log, i can actually just click through the vm object and see a rooms array there, which is the array returned by the datacontext.

Why is this telling me vm.rooms is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
Ended up using $q instead of Q (which is advised anyway, but didn't seem to work before).

Also, in the test i now have a call to the activate method on the controller like this:

```
scope.$digest(vm.activate());
```

That solved it for me.